# Patchplots not working recently?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

While modifying some images that I created using the `patchplots` library from `pgfplots` I noted that the actual colors inside the axis are missing (I had not touched these images for a few weeks and updated MiKTeX in the meantime). Trying to boil down the problem it turns out that not even the example from the manual seems to work anymore. Trying to fix the issue I also updated TikZ and pgfplots to their most recent versions but this did not help.

Can anybody reproduce this issue?

Here is my MWE (basically copied from the manual):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
% build 2013-06-16

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% 2013-06-28 Revision 1.8-39-g32728b1
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[small,view={0}{90}, colorbar]
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,patch type=bilinear]   coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (1,1,1)};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which yields the following output:
[image]

Comment: @Jake: Thank you, copy and paste from the manual messed up the newlines. I will post a new question as this is only the intro to another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of copy and paste from the manual without checking: The newlines were missing which makes all the difference here unfortunately. With

```
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,patch type=bilinear]   coordinates {
        (0,0,0) (1,0,0) 

        (0,1,0) (1,1,1)
        };
```

everything works but I still can't use the image but that is another [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122591/included-image-messes-up-pdf-but-why).

Thanks Jake!

[image]