# Included image messes up pdf but why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots

For some reason including a working colorplot image into a new document via `\includegraphics` seems to modify the image. Is there any workaround to this problem?

My MWE looks harmless:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{colormap.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Colormap.pdf is created by the code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122580/patchplots-not-working-recently) and looks in the correct version very colourful:

[image]

but in the the example document the output is as follows:

[image]

As this problem is most likely related to the included pdf file here is a link: [colormap.pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30565039/colormap.pdf). The resulting broken document is linked here: [include_colormap.pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30565039/include_colormap.pdf)

**Update:**
ImageMagick complains when I want to use the resulting pdf document further:

```
Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
Warning: Form stream has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)
File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.

This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
The file was produced by:
>>>> LuaTeX-0.76.0 <<<<
Please notify the author of the software that produced this
file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
specification.
```

This all happens on Windows using the current LuaTeX from MiKTex 2.9 (Version beta-0.76.0-2013062419 (rev 4627))

Comment: colourmap.pdf and the PDF from your MWE which uses colourmap.pdf look identical here (as they should).

Comment: which tex system are you using?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I use LuaTeX in the most recent version from MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: I used `pdflatex` which produced the expected result. `lualatex` lead to the (bad) result you reported. TeXLive-2013 here.

Comment: @AlexG: Thanks for trying to reproduce the issue. So it is in some way connected to `lualatex`.

Comment: @Alexander looks like you should raise as a possible issue on the luatex list.

Comment: Looks fine here (TL2013 x86_64-linux)

Comment: @AlexG: Could you add which platform and lualatex version you used?

Comment: `This is LuaTeX, Version  beta-0.76.0-2013070317  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)` on Linux x86 32bit

Comment: @AlexG: Thanks, then it is not tied to neither Windows nor MiKTeX.

Comment: Btw, I didn't fetch the included colormap.pdf from your link, but produced it with `pdflatex`. `lualatex` failed on the source (from your other post): `! LuaTeX error ...ve/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/lua/pgfplots.lua:27: attempt to call global 'unpack' (a nil value) stack traceback: ...ve/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/lua/pgfplots.lua:27: in function 'pgfplotsGetLuaBinaryStringFromCharIndices' [string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk. \pgfplotsbinarytoluabinary ...CharIndices({#1}); } l.21     \end{axis} ?`

Comment: @TacoHoekwater judging from the error message in alexG's comment, I assume that the pgfplots lua code is no longer compatible with lualatex. It works well for `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012052410 (TeX Live 2012)`.  Do I need to qualify `unpack` explicitly?

Comment: there is a comment at the bottom of http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.luatex.user/4011 which might be related: apparently, other latex lua packages which rely on unpack produce failures as well. However, my old luatex version doesn't accept `table.unpack`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I cannot reproduce AlexG's issue here. On MiKTeX 2.9 with LuaTeX 0.76 `pgfplots.lua` gets executed without errors and the example document.

Comment: @Alexander could you regenerate the `colormap.pdf` and attach the broken file here? From my point of view, the `colormap.pdf` is entirely correct (I could include it everywhere and my imagemagick can read it, too). Once you you regenerated a broken one, could you collect any warnings  issued by lualatex?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I regenerated `colormap.pdf` and the example as `include_colormap.pdf` (both linked above). I do not get any warnings/errors from LuaTeX for either of those documents. Only processing `include_colormap.pdf` further the warnings, for example from imagemagick appear and the document is broken as shown in the screenshot. So maybe `colormap.pdf` is correct but use a special feature and triggers a bug when included in LuaTeX.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Adobe Illustrator CS 5 complains for `colormap.pdf` that 'An unknown shading type and an unknown imaging construct was encountered' and cannot import the file without breaking it.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Luatex switched to lua 5.2 recently. There is a list of differences and new features here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFiveTwo

Comment: @TacoHoekwater thanks, that is a valueable information! That explains the error of AlexG because lua 5.2 has the changelog entry "unpack() is renamed to table.unpack(). ". Apparently, I will need to add some kind of version switch eventually. Good to know.

Comment: @AlexG what you encountered was an incompatibility. I have fixed it in the pgfplots git repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the included graphics file `colormap.pdf` is correct, this here is a bug in lualatex.

I could track it down: apparently, `lualatex` messes around with the `decode` parameter of the shading.

If you take a text editor, open the `include_colormap.pdf` and make a text substitution below

```
27 0 obj
```

by replacing

```
/Decode[--2147.16352 16384 --2147.16352 16384 0 1]
```

by

```
/Decode[-16383.99992 16384 -16383.99992 16384 0 1]
```

the resulting graphics is entirely correct: it can be viewed and imagemagick does not complain any longer.

This is a bug in lualatex; I do not know why it modified the `/Decode` field in this context.

The solution above would be a valid workaround; these shadings always have the same `decode` array. In other words: you can write some script which applies the search-and-replace until lualatex has been fixed. If you apply the replacement only in the context of  `/ShadingType 6` you will be on the safe side: I do not think that many programs generate such shadings.

Side-note: if you apply search-and-replace in pdf files, you have to keep the number of bytes intact.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to write `\pdfcompresslevel=0` as first line into the file - perhaps thats causing the trouble (just guessing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this investigation Christian! I can confirm that after replacing the offending line the image is restored. I will try with a search and replace script until the lualatex team fixes this bug (pdfcompresslevel unfortunately did not change the wrong decode parameter).

Comment: Ok. Perhaps it is some mistake in the numeric range clipping: -16383.99992 is almost the smallest allowed number, and -2147 are the first digits of the smallest integer. Perhaps some unit conversion mismatch caused the problem.